# how to debug nodejs on openshift?

Tags: node.js, debugging, openshift

In the new version of nodejs (v7.2.1) V8 inspector has been integrated. (experimental feature)

It opens a websocket make it possible to debug source code from remote client.
usage: 
node --inspect=8080 start.js

On OpenShift I get this error:
**Unable to open socket: permission denied**

I tried scaled (HAProxy) and not scaled mode of "node latest" cartridge and got the same error.

Openshift origin (nextGen) may support this?

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks